# Maven dependency resolving in multi module project

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a question about how the Maven dependency resolving mechanism is working in a multi module project.

Normally I only use 'mvn clean install' when I build my multi module projects and my assumption was that if any module in the project needs a previous module, dependency will be resolved by going local repository and loading the corresponding 'jar'.

For project internal reason, I have to use 'mvn clean compile,' this command naturally does not create any 'jar' while 'install' is not there. So here I started wondering, how the dependency resolution for a multi module project works, while jar' is not created but project still able to see the changes from the previous builds. Does the target directories used for dependency management?

Or for 'mvn clean compile' target directory used but for 'mvn clean install' the local repository.

Can anybody explain me how the dependency resolution works in a 'multi module' project.

Thx for answers.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand better if you look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

There is a life cycle in the process of building the jar.  The compile target will compile the code and create a complete classes folder in your target directory.  This target will resolve all your dependencies in your poms and download any dependencies to your local repo, not already there.

The install target will create the jar from the classes directory and install it in your local repository.

I really think you will need to run the install target to get anything useful.

Comment: What I ask has nothing to do lifecycle....I just want to know how Maven resolve inter module dependencies in a multi module project.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is made of separate components.

There a component that deal with a given module and among other things try to get its dependencies. It ALWAYS get the dependencies from the local repository, eventually after having downloaded such dependencies. If the dependencies are not there and can't be dowloaded, it will fail. Eventually the module will create its own artifact that it will publish to the local repo.

Then there a compoment that when you ask it to build several maven modules, for example calling mvn at the root of a project does order the various module use the dependencies to find the best ordering for the build so that if a given module depend on another, it will be build after the module it depend on. It then call the previous compoent I described, building each module in order.

In all cases, a given module dependencies are always taken from the local repo. The expectation is that the previous modules that were built before actually  pushed their artifact to the local repo typically with the mvn install but you could force it do it at any step thanks to proper configuration (may not be a good idea).

In all case if the previous component jar was not built and put into the repo, there no way such jar can be added in the classpath for the next module to be compiled.

Doing compile only on multiple projets isn't going to be any useful.